# Will my apple seedlings survive winter

Tags: houseplants, fruit-trees, indoors, seedlings

I'm growing apple trees. They have been growing for 4 years. I didn’t have a problem with overwintering them since they were in small pots. Now they are in huge plastic ones. Also the weather has a incoming cold snap. For now I have covered them up with bubble wrap and package envelopes. Should I bring them in the garage and put them under a grow light?

Here are some details. They still have leaves but only one has grown a branch. Also one is very tall. And the oldest one I recovered and pruned from being underwater and fungus ridden so its very short. Any ideas or am I worrying? Also all the seedlings have trunks or thick stems. Heres a photo of the tall one that I covered badly
[image]

Comment: What have you done the previous three winters?

Comment: Did you know that apple seedlings from pips do not produce fruit like the apple they came from?

Comment: Where on the planet?

Comment: A 4-year-old sapling is not a seedling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you live in the arctic or anarctic? Do you live above treeline?

If the answer is "no" you should *preferably* plant the trees in the ground where they will live (fall is a good time, spring is an OK time, so which side of the equator is not a big deal) or plunge (bury) the pots in the ground and leave the trees out - depending on your local vermin, some sort of wire mesh protection sleeve is all the trees might require to prevent nibbling by deer and mice/voles/rats/rabbits (bubble wrap is likely to promote problems with mildew & fungus.)

They will (if not eaten) survive the winter, in most locations with some reasonable winter. You should not bring them into the garage under grow lights - they are trees, they expect to spend the winter being dormant, let them do that.

Apple trees are **quite** cold tolerant. Indeed, they typically require a fair bit of cold exposure to set fruit. USDA plant hardiness Zone 3 (-40°F/-40°C minimum temperature) is perfectly fine for most apples. Some varieties will take even colder temperatures.

They are not typically a great choice for a potted plant, as they would appreciate room to grow and become actual trees.

Comment: Extremely hardy from birth.